# MySQL select statement from n database inside stored proc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

After some digging, it looks like a stored procedure is the way to go here but unsure if this is the best solution. I think there is quite a lot to what I am trying to achieve, but will do my best to simplify my problem.

I have a bunch of client databases, all in the exact same structure and all with same table names (legacy issue we inherited which is actively being restructured, but until then I need to take this approach).

What I'd like to do is loop through all these db's and do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_db_a.table1

SELECT * FROM my_db_b.table1

SELECT * FROM my_db_c.table1
```

I understand it is not possible to call a stored procedure from within a view. I was looking for info on for loops within mysql without needing to used a stored procedure but it doesn't look like this is a good approach or even possible for what I am trying to achieve - so a bit unsure how to proceed and find the most efficient solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get to all the databases from the same SQL connection, you could just use a `UNION ALL` between each `SELECT`. This approach would allow you to get the data back from all your database tables in a single result set.

```
SELECT * FROM my_db_a.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_db_b.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM my_db_c.table1
```